# Pseudo 3D fluid domain

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate the following figure from a 20 years old textbook:

[image]

So far i have been able to do the following:

[image]

With the followin Tikz code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,hobby,arrows.meta,3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
scale=0.5,
pin distance=3cm,
every pin/.style={inner sep=1pt},
every pin edge/.style={black,very thick},
line width=2pt,
font=\Huge,
axisProp/.style={x={(-136:2cm)},
y={(-15:2cm)},
z={(90:2cm)}},
axis/.style={x={(-136:2cm)},
y={(-15:4.5cm)},
z={(90:3cm)}}]

\begin{scope}[shift={(-10,-4.7)},axisProp,>=Stealth]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0);
\node at (3.4,0,0) {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,13,0);
\node at (0,13.4,0) {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,9);
\node at (0,0,9.4) {$z$};
\end{scope}
\shade[ball color=green!50,closed hobby] plot coordinates 
{(15.6,-1.6) (14.2,5.4) (8.1,10.3) (1.5,11.5) (-6.2,10.7) (-12.5,7.5) (-16,1)
 (-14,-4.5) (-9,-6.5) (-5.5,-7) (-1.4,-10.3) (2.5,-12) (8,-12) (13.8,-7.4)};
\node at (-13.9,2) {Boundary $D$};
\begin{scope}[shift={(1.7,0.1)},
axis]
\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,2.2) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.1cm,y radius=2.2cm] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,3.1) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.6cm,y radius=3.1cm] -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
\shade[left color=green!50!lightgray,right color=lightgray] 
(0,0) -- +(0,2.2) arc[start angle=90,end angle=0,x radius=3.6cm,y radius=2.2cm] -- cycle;
\coordinate (c1) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (c2) at (1,0); 
\coordinate (c3) at (1,1);
\coordinate (c4) at (0,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
\coordinate (c5) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (c6) at (1,0); 
\coordinate (c7) at (1,1);
\coordinate (c8) at (0,1);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5] 
(c1) -- (c2) -- (c6) -- (c5) -- cycle 
(c1) -- (c4) -- (c8) -- (c5) -- cycle
(c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- cycle;
\draw[red] (c1) -- (c5);
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5]
(c3) -- (c4) -- (c8) -- (c7) -- cycle
(c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c5) -- (c6) -- (c7) -- (c8) -- cycle;
\node[circle,
fill=blue,
minimum size=5mm,
outer sep=0pt,
pin={80:{\Huge $\Delta V$}}] at ($(c5)!0.5!(c3)$){};
\fill[fill=red!50,fill opacity=0.5]
(c2) -- (c3) -- (c7) -- (c6) -- cycle;
\draw[red,join=round] (c2) -- (c6) (c3) -- (c7) (c8) -- (c4) -- (c3) -- (c2) (c6) -- (c7);
\begin{scope}[
every node/.style={circle,minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt},
every pin/.style={inner sep=-5pt,outer sep=0pt},
pin distance=1.35cm
]
\node[pin={300:{\Huge $\Delta x_k$}}] at ($(c3)!0.5!(c4)$){};
\node[pin={220:{\Huge $\Delta y_k$}}] at ($(c2)!0.5!(c3)$){};
\node[pin={30:{\Huge $\Delta z_k$}}] at ($(c4)!0.5!(c8)$){};
\node at (3.1,-0.9) {$\Phi$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But i'm stucked for the creation of the small surface pattern so that it looks like patched on the main surface and the drawing of the four vectors starting from the center of that same surface pattern.

Any help is greatly appreciated.